# Converting JBOSS annotations to xml

Tags: java, jboss, web-services, annotations

I was just hoping that someone could point me to a reference that defines about what JBOSS annotations are equivalent to what xml tags.  I am particularly interested in these tags:

`@WebContext` in `org.jboss.ws.annotation.WebContext`

and

`@SecurityDomain` in `org.jboss.annotation.security.SecurityDomain`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Summary

My understanding is that you need to configure 4 files:

#### web.xml

In this you specify many of the security things

See: http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/Web.xml

#### jboss-web.xml

As Peter mentioned here you specify the security domain

#### jboss-service.xml

This is needed to put any m-beans used into.

#### login-config.xml

This is used to store the login-modual referenced by the security domain.

### Reference

This page gives an awesome description of how to set up client-cert.  It is extremely straight forward to follow.

http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/jboss/jboss-eap-4.3/doc/Server_Configuration_Guide/html/Using_JBoss_Login_Modules-BaseCertLoginModule.html

Answer (score 2):

`@SecurityDomain` is equivalent to `<security-domain>` in the `META-INF/jboss.xml` file:

```
<jboss>
    <security-domain>java:/jaas/other</security-domain>
</jboss>
```

See [this page](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/admindevel326/html/ch8.chapter.html) for more details.

For the other question, I found [this page](http://www.coderanch.com/t/88810/JBoss/Define-web-context-JBoss-other) - hope I could help :-)

Comment: Hmmm, not sure anymore.  I found <a href="http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/Web.xml"> this page </a> which suggests that you can put the tags equivalent to @secuirtyDomain in web.xml.  Anyone have any idea if this is correct?

Answer (score 0):

@Peter Torok got the SecurityDomain annotation.

The WebContext replaces configuration in the jboss.xml in the EJB jar around deploying an EJB as a web service. However, that annotation is difficult if not impossible to fully express in xml. You can see [this issue](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBWS-1309) for more details.